# jquery validate addmethod for textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the `validator.addMethod` in jquery validate to check whether the input is equal to "Contact Name" and if so, ask the user to enter a name:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("contact1", function (value) {
        return value != "Contact Name";
    }, 'Please enter a contact name');
    $.validator.addMethod("message1", function (value) {
        return value != "Message";
    }, 'Please enter a contact name');


    $('.contact-form form').validate({
        rules: {
            contact: {
                "contact1": '',
                required: true
            },
            text: {
                "message1": '',
                required: true
            },

        },
    });
});
```

This works fine for `input="text"` elements, but doesn't work for `textarea` elements. How would I go about getting this to work for a `textarea`?

Edit: sorry left out the `validator.addMethod` I had for the `textarea`

This is what I have in the html:

```
<textarea onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"
        onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" rows="5" id="text" name="text">Message
                                   </textarea>
```

It does call the 'required' correctly but not the logic in the additional `validator.addMethod` function.

Comment: In your rule, you call the method for the text field `message1`; shouldn't it be `text1` to invoke that method?

Comment: It would probably be better to use a jQuery placeholder plugin rather than this ad hoc method for implementing placeholders. Or just use the HTML `placeholder` attribute, and forget about older browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see code error, in your html `input` remember set `name` attribute, validate use it.

Input: http://jsfiddle.net/TBnLH/1/

Textarea: [http://jsfiddle.net/TBnLH/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/TBnLH/5/)

Comment: works fine for input type="text"  but not for text areas any ideas??